# Latex preamble for export to pdf as similar to Word as possible

Tags: conversion, msword

At present, I am writing a lot of stuff in Scrivener. I like using this program to organize, plan and execute my writing. I then compile this into a .tex document, which compiles my references and graphics etc.

Now, I always send my supervisor a word file he can review and comment on, and sometimes correct stuff. The track changes in very useful for this. I could ignore the Latex step, and just jump straight to Word, but this would require setting up the figures, so I feel its easier to just use a LaTeX intermediate step.

My question is, to minimize the formatting issues between LaTeX and word, is there an optimum preamble that people use?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I edited your title with what I understood as your request ... I think that I did a correct edit... Feel free to revert or to change again.

Comment: Thanks, that is much better.

Comment: On topic ... You could use libreoffice to save as open document format (`.odt`)   and then export with the help of `writer2latex` (software or extension of libreoffice) by keeping as much design details as possible (there is an export option for this). If you are open on this solution I can write an answer, but you should add a MWE (minimal working example) to help me add the demonstration.

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't have any issues with using Word as it is. However, I really like using Scrivner and would like to keep that. If I use LibreOffice to write in, then I can add the diagrams and citations from my reference manager. This will render the use of Latex moot. I know Latex is a typesetting tool, but I am using it to compile my references. The only other option is to manually add references and type my bibliography. But I am lazy and like to link into my reference manager (Mendeley), hence the need to compile my references without having to manually add them again in word.

Comment: You could keep working on word ... I said/meant ... just to "Save as" to let the software (LO) export the "tex" document...  It is just a step between `.docx` and `.tex` ... Citations added correct in word could possibly be recognized correctly too in `.odt`  and if so, they could be exported as `.bib` code too. There are options for this too.

Comment: Doesn't Word have the possibility of Citation AddOns? I know there is a Citavi Plugin available, not sure how easy it is to import Mendeley.

Comment: Scrivener let's you use pandoc, which can take care of your citations while creating genuine .docx documents

Comment: Humm, I was not aware Scrivener can use pandoc. I will look into this.